ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.mgmt.eventhub' on synapse notebook even though it is in requirements.txt
We have the azure-management library defined in the requirements.txt:

azure-mgmt-eventhub==11.0.0

But when trying to import the library it is not found:

This has been intermittent for other developers - but it is persistent for the clusters I have worked with. Restarting the sesion or the cluster or reattaching the wheel (or even an updated one) has not changed this behavior.
What might be going on here?

As per the Microsoft Azure SDK for Python, you can install the Microsoft Azure Event Hub Management Client Library using the command pip install azure-mgmt-eventhub.
As you mentioned, you are using the requirements.txt file. I have tried the following approach:
Step 1:
I created a requirements.txt file containing azure-mgmt-eventhub==11.0.0.
Step 2:
I uploaded it to the Spark pool.

Step 3:
Next, after uploading, I tried:
from azure.mgmt.eventhub import EventHubManagementClient

Results:
import pkg_resources
for d in pkg_resources.working_set:
     print(d)




The issue was that the requirements.txt file attached to the Synapse Spark Pool had not been updated.   So the azure-mgmt-eventhub-11.0.0 library was in the source code / ADO file but was not in the file used to set up the Spark Pool.
Note that the date listed on the file was v recent (yesterday). I'm not sure what that date refers to since the actual contents were from a version six weeks old.
